# How to get the particular process cpu usage from task manager in windows using python?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, cpu-usage

I need to get the particular process cpu usage from task manager using python.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library.

For getting process

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process(<ProcessID>)
print(p.cpu_percent(interval=1.0))
```

This will give you the float representation of the current system-wide CPU utilization as a percentage by a process.

Also if you are having any trouble in retrieving any running process PID you can again use psutil library as :

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name() == <Some Running Process Name> :
        try:
            pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid'])
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            pass
        else:
            print(pinfo)
```

It will give you pid inside a dictionary thou.

Comment: I can't match the numbers obtained here with those I find in Process Explorer.